# how to open a file in tkiner window and than make it accessible to the other functions of the script

Tags: pandas, tkinter

I'm so new to programming that I would not even call me a beginner programmer. I need help because I am writing a program and I would love to make a tkinter G.u.i.. Basicly the program will open a file of my choice with askopenfilename, and that process the data contained. The problem is that I create a variable named df (its a dataframe containing 3 columns of data s, v, i), and than, I would like that clicking a button, You could perform a function over It. but the variable df only exists within the askopenfilename function. 
How can i perform a function, over a variable, that has been created in another function?
I hope to have described everything, thanks to everyone!

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
from scipy.stats import linregress
window= tk.Tk()

#askopenfilename function
def fileopen():
    df= tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
#the function that I want to apply over the data loaded 
def Lineweaver(x,y):                       
    s= 1/x                                 
    v=1/y
    slope,intercept,r_value,p_value,std_err=linregress(s,v)
    slope, intercept
    m=slope
    q=intercept
    l=list((m,q))
    return(l)
# buttons
third_button= tk.Button(text='open file', width= 30, command = fileopen)
third_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W')
first_button = tk.Button(text='linearizz', command=Lineweaver(df['s'], df['v']))
first_button.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky='W')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: declare `global` in your `fileopen` function, i.e. `global df` then `df= tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()`